# How does the shebang execute the program?

Tags: executable, shebang

I feel like a total noob asking this question, but I'm wondering, how does the shebang in a program (*Ex*: `#!/usr/bin/env python`) execute it?

I know that the file is run by `./filename`, but how does it run it with the right executor?

Would it be the same as running it with the `python` command? If so, how does the shebang redirect it to the command?

Comment: The shebang line _specifies_ the right "executor". That's how it is found (by the [program loader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loader_%28computing%29))

Comment: @SergioTulentsev How is the file executed from there on out? Does it pass the filename to the program? (Would it pass `filename` to `python`?) Or is it like a symbolic link pointing towards the actual python program?

Comment: One does not exclude the other :) You can think of `/usr/bin/env python` as a "symlink" to currently installed python, yes.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sergio Answered:

> The shebang line specifies the right "executor". That's how it is found (by the [program loader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loader_%28computing%29)).