# How can I run a .py without reviewing its first line in a shell to avoid incompatibility?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, shebang

If there is a test.py file like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
print 'a'
```

And if I simply type in my Linux shell like this:

```
$ python test.py
```

Then it will get wrong because 'python' means I will specify an interpreter to run it which I find is version 3.5.2.In another word,it will ignore the comment in the first line.

So if I do not know the version of the interpreter of a py file and I know there is a comment in the py file's first line to specify its version,how can I execute it without reviewing its first line in a shell to avoid possible incompatibility issues?

Comment: Related: [How does the shebang execute the program?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39547588/364696)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the first line as intended:

```
$ ./test.py
```

Note that your python file must be executable for this to work. You can accomplish this with the following line:

```
$ chmod +x ./test.py
```

Comment: I tried it.I didn't work.

Comment: The code means run test.py in a default version of interpreter which is the same as 'python test.py' in a shell.

Comment: What do you mean, "didn't work"? What shell are you using? What operating system? What error are you getting? What are you typing into the command line?

Comment: .It's a default shell of Ubuntu16.04 LTS.I mean

Comment: It's a default shell of Ubuntu16.04 LTS.I mean the result of 'chmod +x ./test.py && ./test.py' is the same as 'python test.py' .

Comment: What happens if you run '/usr/bin/env python2' in the command line?

Comment: Sorry,I forget to modify some details.Thanks,it works.Good answer!

Comment: Sorry,I forget to modify some details.Adding the comment #!/usr/bin/env python2 in the .py is enough.

Comment: Can you select this as the answer then? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

to add on the subject, the first line is a shebang.  I suggest you read this is you want to know more :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)